# Atom won't start from the command line

Tags: atom-editor, macos-high-sierra

I updated OSX to High Sierra and my Atom stopped working from the command line.

`$ atom .
FSPathMakeRef(/Applications/Atom.app) failed with error -36.`

I a have uninstalled Atom and reinstalled Atom and ran "Install Shell Commands". :/

any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run Atom by clicking on the icon in the Applications folder. Once Atom is running go to the Atom menu and click on the "Install Shell Commands". Next time you want to run atom, type atom on a terminal command line. If this doesn't work try putting the following statement in your .bash_profile

```
alias atom="Applications/Atom.app/Contents/MacOs/Atom"
```

Comment: Sorry, I worded that question poorly... I had Installed Shell Commands.  I hav edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: i added to my answer something you could try. This should work for any app.

Comment: I got a similar error when trying to run IntelliJ IDEA from the command line. Solution: Tools-> Create Command-line Launcher